# Something works in debug mode but not in normal mode

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, ear, ibm-rad, rational-rsa

I have a web app running in websphere **WAS 6.1** (under IBM RSA).

It consists of **two EARs**, each of them with **one web module** (WAR).

The app has a menu that is loaded as a result of a xsl+xsql parsing.

The case is that if we launch the server in **normal mode**, the menu is not loaded properly, but when we launch the server in **debug mode**, the menu is loaded properly.

Does somebody have any clues of what could be happening here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved,

In the classpath, there was a library called xmlparserv2.jar, with a "problematic" xslt processor (under javax.xml.transform basis).

Removing it from the project, do the thing.

Now, other library does the xslt transformation (under org.apache.xalan.xslt basis).

This post helped me a lot: What processor is javax.xml.transform Using?

Answer (score 2):

WebSphere Application Server uses different XML engines for normal mode and debug mode, and it sounds like you've found a variance between them.  You should double-check that your code is following the javadoc (i.e., you're not doing something with undefined behavior), and if that's not the case, considering opening a PMR with IBM to fix the problem in normal or debug mode (it could be that debug mode should also be failing...).  Alternatively, consider moving up to a newer version; 6.1 is quite old, and your problem might be fixed in a later version of the product.

Comment: Thanks, we are going to consider upgrade our old RSA 7.0.0.6